# Compile error while calling updateStateByKey

Tags: spark-streaming, apache-spark-1.4

Compile Error :

```
The method updateStateByKey(Function2<List<Integer>,Optional<S>,Optional<S>>) in the type JavaPairDStream<String,Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (Function2<List<Integer>,Optional<Integer>,Optional<Integer>>)
```

In a  simple word count example , mapping the words with 1

```
JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = words.mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<>(s,1));
```

And then applying `updateStateByKey` on `wordCounts`

```
 JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> finalcount =  wordCounts.updateStateByKey(updateFunction);
```

The `updateFunction` is defined as follows:

```
 final Function2<List<Integer>, Optional<Integer>, Optional<Integer>> updateFunction =
                    new Function2<List<Integer>, Optional<Integer>, Optional<Integer>>() {
                      @Override
                      public Optional<Integer> call(List<Integer> values, Optional<Integer> state) {
                        Integer newSum = state.orElse(0);
                        for (Integer value : values) {
                          newSum += value;
                        }
                        return Optional.of(newSum);
                      }
                    };
```

The updateStateByKey has following recommended signatures available:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please check which package you import for using Optional. Spark use com.google.common.base.Optional not jdk default package java.util.Optional.